How to Address Security Warnings About Named Credentials When Handling OAuth in Apex?
I am preparing to submit my Salesforce application for review to list it on Salesforce AppExchange. My application uses a custom OAuth authentication flow handled by an LWC component and Apex. The access token, refresh token, and expiry are stored in a protected custom metadata type, and I manage token expiry within my Apex code whenever making API callouts.
Here's a snippet of my current implementation:
httpReq.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
httpReq.setMethod('POST');
httpReq.setBody(requestBody);
httpReq.setEndpoint(myDotNetEndPoint);
httpReq.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);

I have encountered security warnings from the Salesforce scanner suggesting the use of named credentials for authentication:
2   3   ApiController.cls  76  23  ApexSuggestUsingNamedCred  Suggest named credentials for authentication  https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.55.0/pmd_rules_apex_security.html#apexsuggestusingnamedcred
Security    pmd
While I understand the benefits of named credentials, I have not used them because they require manual authentication. My current approach automates the OAuth flow and securely handles tokens via custom metadata types.
I have read documentation suggesting the use of protected custom metadata types to store sensitive information. Given this, will my application still pass the Salesforce security review despite these warnings? What steps can I take to mitigate this issue or improve my current approach?
Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated, as I am new to working with Salesforce security reviews.
Thank you!

You can state that this is a false positive in your false positives document you submit as part of the review, and include explanation that you need this to be fully self-contained, without the need for admin intervention after package install. BTW, are you packaging a remote site setting to allow access to the end point? Does the end point vary, or is it always the same? If it varies then admins would have to add a remote site setting after install, which somewhat negates the argument.

The endpoint will not vary, it is always same. will check the possibilities to provide explanation for this at the time of review submission.
